# How to get current working directory of another drive in Batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there a way to get the current working directory of a drive **other than the current drive**?

Windows stores the current directory of every drive and `%cd%` gets the current working directory of the actual drive.

If I change the drive in a batch script I can get the current working directory of the actual drive:

```
cd w:\Downloads
cd c:\Windows
c:
(echo %cd%)
w:
(echo %cd%)
```

Is there a way to get the current working directory **without** changing the actual drive?

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. In Windows there is only one current directory. For compatibility with MSDOS CMD.Exe pretends there are per drive current directories.

Comment: @CatCat maybe is "current directory" not the best choice to name it. But AFAIK "the system remembers the last current path for each volume (drive letter)" (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/FileIO/changing-the-current-directory) and the system stores those "last current paths" in those "strange variables" (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100506-00/?p=14133). See my answer below

Comment: @CatCat: You're right. See update of my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After searching for an answer I found some hints on *strange variables* under https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100506-00/?p=14133

use `%=c:%)` for the current directory of drive c or `%=w:%)` for w

Or in a batch script:

```
cd c:\Windows
cd w:\Downloads
(echo %=c:%)
(echo %=w:%)
```

**UPDATE**

As @RossRidge pointed out it is not Windows storing those *strange variables* but the DOS command processor. Those *strange variables* are only known in the current 'session'. The same holds for `cd` (see comment of @Stephan)

Opening two DOS command processors:

In the first DOS command processor:

```
cd c:\Windows
cd w:\Downloads
(echo %=c:%)
    -> c:\Windows
(echo %=w:%)
    -> w:\Downloads
cd w:
    -> w:\Downloads
```

In the second DOS command processor:

```
(echo %=w:%)
    -> %=w:%       <- this variable is not set, not known
cd w:
    -> w:\
```

Notice the inconsistent way to hold the 'current directory': `cd` returns the root directory after entering a DOS command processor. But `%=w:%` is not set until the directory changes!

Comment: You'll also notice that Windows doesn't actually store the current directory of every drive: "Win32 does not have the concept of a separate current directory for each drive, but the command processor wanted to preserve the old MS-DOS behavior because people were accustomed to it (and batch files relied upon it). The solution was to store this "per-drive current directory" in the environment, using a weird-o environment variable name so it wouldn't conflict with normal environment variables."

Comment: @RossRidge: Thanks for your comment. See the update of my answer.

Comment: if you just want to know it, also `cd w:` tells you. (But in a batch script, those varables are surely more helpful.)

Comment: @Stephan: Thanks for the hint. See update of my answer.