# How to get the current working directory of another drive?

Tags: c#, environment-variables

I need to get the current working directory of another drive than the current drive.
From reading the answer to 
[How to get current working directory of another drive in Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53078528/how-to-get-current-working-directory-of-another-drive-in-batch)
I know that this information is stored in the environment variables passed to my process by cmd.exe (or whatever shell I'm using). But the C# class Environment does not seem to get me access to those.

Basically, I am looking for the equivalent of the batch command

```
w:
cd w:\foo
c:
cd c:\bar
echo %=w:%
```

In that example, I want to get "w:\foo", but Environment.CurrentDirectory will obviously give me "c:\bar".

I'm looking for something like Environment.GetCurrentDirectory("w:").

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. There is only one working directory...?

Comment: @John: a process has only one working directory. But, each drive letter also has an associated "current directory". I.e. if in your command prompt your current directory is on the `C:` drive, and you type `cd d:\some\sub\directory`, your current directory will still be whatever it was, but now if you change your current drive by typing `D:`, you'll find that the current directory on _that_ drive was set to `\some\sub\directory`. It's a weird little quirk of DOS/Windows, but it does work.

Comment: @Peter Interesting. I had no idea!

Answer (score 2):

The other answer works fine. But I find it a bit incomprehensible. You have to know too much about Windows and its little quirks to understand why it works.

An alternative that is more directly in line with the intrinsic .NET API would be to use `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath()`. I.e.:

```
string currentDirectoryForC = Path.GetFullPath("C:");
string currentDirectoryForD = Path.GetFullPath("D:");
```

The `GetFullPath()` method takes a path given in any valid format, including relative as above, and converts it to whatever the actual absolute path would be, given the current state of everything.

IMHO, the whole thing about drive letters, current directories for a drive, and the working directory for a program, has always bugged me since DOS 1.0 (and CP/M for that matter). The best thing in a .NET program (or a program in any other environment for that matter) is to just always work with full paths.

But, if you really need to know the current directory on a specific drive letter, the above will do it. :)

I will also point out that there is a subtle difference between these two approaches: it's possible to change the current directory from within a process, e.g. by doing something like `Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"D:\some\sub\directory";` even while the program's working directory is on the `C:` drive. But the "magic environment variables" values are fixed when the program starts, and so using the `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` technique will still return whatever the current directory for the drive was before the program started, not the new value.

The `Path.GetFullPath()` method will still do the correct thing in this case, returning the newly-set current directory for that drive.

Frankly, *changing* the current directory for a drive is even wonkier than changing the process's current working directory, even if one accepts it makes sense to get that current directory. So I'm not saying this is a terribly important difference. But it exists nonetheless, and may affect one's decision about which technique to use, depending on what they expect to happen should the process's current directory for a specific drive change.

Comment: I agree on using full paths, and I do internally. Unfortunately I am receiving input that aren't always full paths. The Path.GetFullPath() approach sounds like it will work just fine for my purpose. Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick: _"I am receiving input that aren't always full paths"_ -- I'm not sure how knowing the current directory for a drive letter helps there though. Any valid path passed to your program, you should be able to pass directly to any file API and let it figure it out. If you need to know what the full path is, you can just pass that path directly to `Path.GetFullPath()` and let it do all the work. At no point should your program need to know what the current directory of the drive letter actually is, at least for those scenarios. Maybe you're doing something else?

Comment: @Patrick Yes, you should clarify your use case. This may be an example of an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` is the `.NET` method for retrieving environment variables, and I have just tried this and observed that it works just like in that question you linked to:

```
// Current C: working directory
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("=c:")

// Current D: working directory
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("=d:")
```

Comment: Doh! I should have thought of trying that. I did use Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables() to see if they would be returned, but they weren't.

Comment: @Patrick That's probably because they're not actual environment variables, but are sort of "virtual" environment variables. The Windows shell has a bunch of such things that you can access with `%something%`.